# PHP & MySQL: Как организовать логику?

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Я создал в MySQL таблицу с учениками.
Мне необходимо по каждому ученику вести учет активности. С возможностью добавления, удаления и редактирования полей. И дальнейшего уже вывода на странице.

На странице это должно выглядеть примерно так:[image: таблица]

Но я еще плохо разбираюсь в пхп и БД, и не понимаю логику, как это сделать.
Т.е. пока у меня получилось создавать и выводить только по одному полю и так-же их изменять.
В таблице у меня: id, имя, день недели, действие и количество.
Но это не правильно. Или мне нужно под каждого ученика создавать отдельную таблицу?

Comment: под каждого ученика не надо отдельную, надо данные дробить - список учеников отдельно, типы упражнений отдельно и тд, а связывать их с помощью общего идентификатора.

Comment: Чтобы точнее понять что у вас не так, приведите минимальный пример и структуру БД.